# Trouble with frame when adding a gradient layer to grouped UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell Subclass that I add an overlay gradient like this:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        // add a layer that overlays the cell adding a subtle gradient effect
        _gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        _gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        _gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f] CGColor],
                                  (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor],
                                  (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                                  (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor]];
        _gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.00f, @0.01f, @0.95f, @1.00f];
        [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer atIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // ensure the gradient layers occupies the full bounds
    _gradientLayer.frame = self.contentView.frame;
}
```

The problem is, the gradient doesn't cover the space my Accessory View takes up:
[image]

and you can also see in the top left corner that it doesn't curve either.

How can I get the gradient to take up the full cell space?

EDIT-----

As suggested below, i've added:

```
+(Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}
```

and changed the cell's init method to:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        _gradientLayer = (CAGradientLayer*)self.layer;
        _gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f] CGColor],
                                  (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor],
                                  (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                                  (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor]];
        _gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.00f, @0.01f, @0.95f, @1.00f];
    }
    return self;
}
```

However, now the gradients show like this:
[image]

EDIT 2 ---------
Tarks suggestion below, using a gradient in a UIView then assigning to the cell's background gives this result!
[image]

Comment: The `xcode` tag should be synonimized with `cocoa-touch`... So much abuse... -.-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work as solution in your case:

Use a asset/dynamicaly created gradient-Image and use `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:gradientImage]` for setting the `backgroundColor` property of your cell.

If you want to use your layer solution, you have to set a mask to your gradientlayer, but the shape of the mask depends on the position of the cell in the section and so on...

You Should avoid using transparency/alpha in your gradient, at least in your example you do not need it.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to not have to use an image. Plus the gradient is just an overlay to go over a background colour which can be changed by the user, so the alpha gradient gives the effect.

Comment: After wasting the day playing around on this. You solution is the only one that has worked and I am happy with it now. I was worried I couldn't duplicate the gradient in an image as I use the same one else where, however in the end I managed to save the CAGradientLayer to file then trim it to 1px wide and use it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do it in a different way. In your subclass override the `+layerClass` method:

```
+(Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}
```

This way, your top layer of your cell will be gradient layer. Then just cast your `self.layer` to `CAGradientLayer` and set its colors and locations.

Comment: Yeah, this is better than my answer. This way, the gradient is resized automatically as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. Would I then set the gradient in the cellForRowAtIndexPath instead of in the cell's init method?

Comment: Please see the edit to my question. This now extends outwards. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The accessory and editing views are added outside the content view - the content view doesn't always fill the cell.

Set your layer's frame to be self.bounds, not self.contentView.frame.

Comment: This makes the gradient extend out the sides of the cells

Comment: Oh, you're using a grouped layout. Tricky. What happens if you try the bakgroundView of the cell instead of the cell itself?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to get this working is to use the `backgroundView` property of the cell. Otherwise you are always going to have issues with the cell border and accessory views. Simply wrap the gradient layer in a UIView and then set this as the background view. Someone has already done this if you want to be lazy:

https://github.com/ole/OBGradientView

You will also have to set the `selectedBackgroundView` property if you want that as a gradient too.

Comment: this will not work in this case, as he is using a grouped layout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. See the edit of my question for image.